# PHP fastest way to check list of domains

Tags: php, performance, ip, host, resolve

I have a list of 20.000 domains I want to resolve into IP addresses. I am looking for the **fastest way** to do that in php.

I used `gethostbynamel()` but that is too slow. I am looking for **another command that can filter out the hosts that do not exist** at all and then run `gethostbynamel()`

1. I have tried `checkdnsrr("host.com","A")` but that is too slow.
2. `curl` is also too slow.

Comment: It should be because of the response time of the servers you are connecting to, not just because of the functions. Maybe you should find a faster DNS server or something.

Comment: Considered multithreading to reduce total runtime? http://tinyurl.com/3tr6dkh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't get any faster. You'll have to contact each domain to see if they're available. Even with an avarage roundtriptime of about 50ms you will need more that 15 minutes to check out all 20000 domains. And that is if you don't have to wait for time-outs.

You will only get faster if you make this multi-threaded. You can easily setup 10 threads to connect to 10 servers in parallel, which cuts the processing time in 10 too.

But PHP is not really designed for multi threading, so you might want to use another tool.

But why on earth do you want to check out 20.000 domains? It must be something fishy..

Comment: haha no. I am trying to create my own anti distraction tool. It is supposed to block websites. If I want to block facebook, i need to combine facebook wit 267 top level domains and resolve all of those. If I have 100 websites times 267 are quite a lot sites...

Answer (score 0):

- get better internet connection speed
- if CURL is slow, it's the fastest way

Comment: A fast connection won't help with DNS resolving. it's entirely dependent on the DNS server you're querying.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- assuming it's possible for the addresses to be incorrect, run a regex to validate their format prior to attempting to resolve them.
- sort addresses that belong to the same domain into similar groups, and check that domain once for the group, instead of for each address
- does this need to be run multiple times or just once? If multiple times, you may consider caching the ips using a cache such as apc or zend cache, or store the IPs some other way (file or db), and test that ip to see if it resolves, and if not, try a new dns call
- separate the task into multiple subtasks (several php processes)
- determine what the fastest DNS server is for you, and use that. [Pear has a net dns](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS/redirected) package with functionality that might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the pear tip! I found a dns resolve example where i can specify faster DNS servers [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-dns.net-dns-resolver.query.php) Do you know if I have to install the pear packages on my server first or if I can just include the DNS.php? thanks

Answer (score 0):

script1.php

```
<?
if (!$argv[1]) exit;
$ip = gethostbynamel($argv[1]);
// do something
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?
$domains = array();
foreach($domains as $domain){
  shell_exec("php script1.php $domain");
}
?>
```

Might run out of memory though.